# Generate tsql color-number Permutation

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, permutation

I've got this example table:

```
CREATE TABLE Balls 
(
    BallId  int primary key identity(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    Color   char(1) NOT NULL,
    Number  int NOT NULL
)
```

I've got balls with different colors and each ball has a number on it. An example of data in the table:

```
BallId  Color   Number
4       G       1
9       G       2
1       R       1
2       R       2
3       R       3
5       W       1
6       W       2
7       W       3
8       W       4
```

I need all permutations of all different balls together (in this case G-R and W) with the number. 
For example:

```
G1 R1 W1
G1 R1 W2
G1 R1 W3 
G1 R1 W4
G1 R2 W1
...
G2 R3 W4
```

And "G1 R1 W1" is equal to "R1 G1 W1" (order doesn't matter). 
I need the tsql script to generate this permutation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is G1 G2 R1 or R1 R2 R3 a possible result? or does a valid result require one ball of each color?

Comment: Valid results are only with each color balls

Answer (score 0):

Joining tables will produce a permutation unless you do something to limit the results.

```
select g.color, g.number, r.color, r.number, w.color, w.number

from Balls g, Balls r, Balls w
where g.color = 'G' 
  and r.color = 'R'
  and w.color = 'W'
```

Comment: I need a scalable solution... your one works only with three colors... :(

Comment: Never suggest using sql antipatterns like implicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL to have a scalable solution:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @Parm NVARCHAR(30)
SET @sql = N'SELECT @SQL2 = ''SELECT ''+STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '', T''+COLOR+''.COLOR'' + ''+CAST(T''+ COLOR +''.NUMBER AS NVARCHAR(2))''  as ''data()'' FROM Balls FOR XML PATH('''')),1,2,'''')'+' (SELECT DISTINCT ''FROM ''+STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '', Balls T''+COLOR ''data()'' FROM Balls FOR XML PATH('''')),1,2,'''')) +'' WHERE ''+ STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '' AND T''+ COLOR +''.COLOR'' + '' = '' +  + '''''''' + COLOR + '''''''' as ''data()'' FROM Balls FOR XML PATH('''')),2,3,'''')    '
SET @Parm = N'@SQL2 varchar(MAX) OUTPUT'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @Parm, @SQL2=@SQL2 OUTPUT
EXEC (@SQL2)
```

See [this SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed749/1/0) for testing.